# Trying to update data in chart.js chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, chart.js, destructuring

I want to have a dynamic dataset in a chart, which takes in value from an API and utilizes it as data in the chart. So I expected the chart to display the data, but instead, it shows nothing console logging the variable which is an array that contains the data inside the function where the graph is shows nothing, not even `undefined`, other when the meta-information in the dev tools as what line it's at (Weirdly enough I have console. logs early in the code, yet it shows this one first).

I've tried creating an array called `weatherData`, initially it's empty. When inside a function where it has the object literal form of the API data as an argument, it does the following.

```
function dataArray(data) {
  weatherData.length = 0;

  const { temp, feels_like, temp_min, temp_max } = data.main;

  weatherData.push(temp);
  weatherData.push(feels_like);
  weatherData.push(temp_min);
  weatherData.push(temp_max);

  return weatherData; 
}
```

And then inside another function called `graphing` it suppose to get the array and destructer it then use each index as a data inside the data section like this, but apparently not even receiving the array itself is working, as shown by the console log

```
const graphing = () => {
  // * Shows a blank log of it
  console.table(weatherData)
  
  // * Creating local variables from the array
  const [ temperature, feelsLike, minimumTemperature, maximumTemperature ] = weatherData;

  let ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Temperature', 'Feels Like', 'Maximum Temperature', 'Minimum Temperature'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Temperature',
              // * The data section
              data: [temperature, feelsLike, minimumTemperature, maximumTemperature],
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 2.5
          }]
      }...// * Other things that have been omitted, that are about how the graph should look like
```

The function of `graphing` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DOM by clearing the parent element of the chart's canvas element, and when recreating the canvas element, assigning it the id of `chart` as needed in the variable of `ctx`, and when appending that to the parent element of the former canvas element works indeed. All in the `graphing` function, and when simply calling the graphing function where need be.